# Deserializing JSON string to C#

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, jsonserializer

I have a JSON array, which looks like this:

```
{[
  {
    "personnelId": 201,
    "occupationIds": [
      4,
      5
    ]
  },
  {
    "personnelId": 202,
    "occupationIds": [
      5
    ]
  }
]}
```

I'm receiving this string through a `JObject` in my ASP.NET Web API controller:

```
var jPersonnelAndOccupationIds = json["personnelAndOccupationIds"];
```

I've had success deserialiizing various data structures through `JObject` but this keeps giving a `RuntimeBinderException`, what data structure would be best suited for that JSON string, I've tried a lot of thing, this IMO is the most suitable `List<PersonnelOccupationsVm>` where `PersonnelOccupationsVm` looks like this:

```
public class PersonnelOccupationsVm
    {

        public long personnelId { get; set; }
        public List<long> occupationIds { get; set; }
    }
```

which I desrialize like this:

```
var personnelIdsAndOccupationsKvp = jPersonnelAndOccupationIds.ToObject(new List<PersonnelOccupationsVm>());
```

and I've tried

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<PersonnelOccupationsVm>>(jPersonnelAndOccupationIds);
```

neither works. any ideas?

**EDIT**

As requested in the comments, I'm making my call like this (angular):

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/api/EnterprisePersonnelApi/SubmitOcupationalPersonnel/',
  data: JSON.stringify({ enterpriseId: enterpriseId, positionId: positionId,personnelAndOccupationIds: personnelAndOccupationIds }),
  }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                      deferred.resolve(data);
  }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                     deferred.reject(status);
});
```

and my web api action:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public CrudOperationResults SubmitOcupationalPersonnel(JObject jsonData){
dynamic json = jsonData;
var jPersonnelAndOccupationIds = json["personnelAndOccupationIds"];
var personnelIdsAndOccupations = jPersonnelAndOccupationIds.ToObject(new List<PersonnelOccupationsVm>());
.....
}
```

this given a `RunTimeBinderexception`, however when I call `.ToString()` while retrieving values from the `JObject` instance:

```
var jPersonnelAndOccupationIds = json["personnelAndOccupationIds"].ToString();
```

and (per shunty's suggestion)

```
var jPersonnelAndOccupationIds = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PersonnelOccupationsVm>>(jPersonnelAndOccupationIds);
```

this works fine, the leading and trailing curly braces were added while retieving my parameter values from JObject, calling `.ToString()` and deserializing it per above did the trick.

Comment: What you have shown is invalid JSON. JSON arrays should start with `[` and end with `]`. In your example there seems to be some wrapping `{` and `}`. Also what is the `json` variable you used here: `json["personnelAndOccupationIds"]`? Where does it come from? It looks like you are attempting to deserialize the JSON string twice.

Comment: Agree that the JSON is invalid. Try http://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a particularly proficient Json user but, using the Newtonsoft stuff I'd try something like this (cut and pasted from [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net)):

```
void Main()
{
    string json = "[{ \"personnelId\": 201, \"occupationIds\": [4,5]}, {\"personnelId\": 202,\"occupationIds\": [5]}]";

    var js = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PersonnelOccupationsVm>>(json);
    js.Dump();

}

public class PersonnelOccupationsVm
{
    public int PersonnelId { get; set; }
    public List<int> OccupationIds { get; set; }

    public PersonnelOccupationsVm()
    {
        OccupationIds = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Note that I had to trim the leading and trailing { } characters from the source Json.